# System crashes when added a button inside group item in an Expandable ListView?

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview, textview

I'm trying to add a button to the group view of a expandable list view. When I tried the below code it didn't work (this code has a textview, textview and button both didn't work), it crashed and I have uploaded the exception as well. I have shown the crashing point in the code below.

Can anyone tell me whats the mistake I have made or the change I need to make in my adapter,

```
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_group, parent, false);
        }

        TextView groupName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        TextView groupQty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_qty);
        TextView groupSubtotal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblsubtotal);

        Product cat = _cartList.get(groupPosition);

        groupName.setText(cat.description);
        groupQty.setText(String.valueOf(cat.quantity));
        groupSubtotal.setText(Double.toString(cat.subTotal));

        TextView editTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblsubtotccal); //crashes here
        editTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent next = new Intent(_context, ActivityCustomize.class);

                _context.startActivity(next);
                ((Activity) _context).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v` for accessing all view's from `cart_list_group`  layout. currently using `convertView` which i causing issue due to `null`:

```
    TextView editTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblsubtotccal);
```

Comment: yh that was the issue. I was trying this for long time. thanks alot for spotting it :)